# Why don't the picture's max-width match with the other elements' max-width on the posts?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Even if its source is wider than the post, the pictures don't follow the other elements' max-width. For a better layout, the pictures should have the same max-width or, at least, be aligned by the center.

*Example of the current (Apr 8 at 22:00) max-width of the elements:*

[image: detail with lines]

To let it better to compare, here's [the same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527342/html5-positioning-aside-figure-section) with 3 different image settings:

**A-** Regular post with text, code and a wide screenshot:

[image: regular post]

**B-** The same post (**edited on the Photoshop**) with the screenshot **aligned by the center:**

[image: regular post aligned]

**C-** Finally, the post (**edited on the Photoshop**) with it's screenshot sharing the **same max-width** of the text/code blocks:

[image: regular post wider]

Comment: No repro on Windows 64 bit, Firefox 45.0.1

Comment: Repro on Chrome 49.0.2623.112

Comment: Reproducible on Windows 10, Edge 25.10586 and IE 11.162.

Comment: Repro on El Capitan with Chrome 51.0.2700.0 dev, and Safari 9.1.1 (11601.6.14) (normal Safari) and 9.1.1 (11601.6.10, 11602.1.25) (technology preview).

Comment: Don't know how this wouldn't be reproducible. The CSS is pretty straightforward: `.post-text{ width:660px } .post-text img{ max-width:630px }`. I bet at some point they made `.post-text` wider and forgot that the width was also defined on the nested `img` elements.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Repro on Google Chrome 48.0.2564.103 (Linux)

Comment: Reproducible on Windows 7: IE 11.0.9600.18230, FireFox 38.0.5, and Chrome 49.0.2623.112 m.

Comment: yes it is so. But I don't like when they are full-width, and all the more centered - would look horrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks. We're pushing a fix now. Should be live in the next production server build (soon.)