# Forgotten element at new color theme?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

April 2016 - StackOverflow color theme has been improved as we see in the pictures:

**before**:

[image: before]

**after**:

[image: then]

But the **'next privilege' tracker** seems to be forgotten and is **missing contrast** (mainly the arrows):

[image]

**Shouldn't it be improved as well?**

Comment: Good catch. Thanks. That's a bug, we'll fix it.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers The reputation graphs need updated too.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ rep graph looks find to me, mind posting more details either as a comment or as a separate bug post (if screenshot is needed to illustrate the bug)?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers [Here ya go](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321423/reputation-graph-color)

Comment: @KurtisBeavers since you're currently changing the website layout, please take a look [**on this post**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320701/5875416) as well;

Comment: Always glad to see improvements, but the Answers/Accepted change from the old white to amber text to the new faded green (unanswered) green (answered) doesn't look so good. Understandably, that's just my opinion and I'm sure others feel differently. Just thought I would provide a bit of feedback. (I can live with it either way...)

Comment: @freestock.tk fixing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for this is set to go out with the next production build. Thanks for letting us know about it.