# Reputation Graph Color

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

The reputation graph on the Activity/Summary tab doesn't appear to have gotten the fresh new green color that has been released.

[image: reputation graph]

```css
.user-show-new .user-rep-chart-summary .user-rep-chart-summary-bar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 13px;
    background-color: #a9d9a4;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This does not match the either of the new greens `#4ca143;` `#dcf0da`, it should look something like this:

[image: rep graph updated]

Comment: Suggestion: It could stay like it is (light green) and become (regular) green on `:hover`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously the graph used a lighter green, so we attempted only to match the color to our updated green colors. I did like **freestock.tk**'s suggestion though:

> Suggestion: It could stay like it is (light green) and become (regular) green on `:hover`

I've implemented that added feature and it will be live in the next production build. Otherwise the lighter green is intentional here.

**P.S.** As I was writing this post, I noticed that the code background is the same as the blockquote background on Meta.SO, so I've gone ahead and updated that as well.

Comment: The original green on the graph doesn't appear to match either of the new greens though, shouldn't that be changed to the lighter green at least? There is 3 greens being used `#a9d9a4;` `#4ca143;` `#dcf0da;` contrary to [Nicks comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321413#comment-335195), *One green to rule them all. Except that other, lighter green. Okay, so two greens to rule them all. – Nick Craver*

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ Technically we have 10 greens. All of our greens are based off the `#65BB5C` color. We have 4 lighter steps before it and 5 darker steps after it. This allows us to have a variety of greens, but they all share the same hue and saturation. That was the major problem before. Not that we had more than 1, 2, or 3 greens. They were all different hues and saturations as well.

Comment: Well, that makes sense now. Thanks for clarifying. Out of curiosity, do you guys have a list of those colors available?

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ We don't have a list of colors public just yet, but we will post them. We're still finalizing some of the colors.

Comment: Is the next production build already deployed? I see the changes at my end.

Comment: The hover thing seems pointless to me. It's not conveying any additional information; it's just mildly distracting.