# New colour scheme for Next Privilege bar too light

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, design

Is the new colour scheme for the `Next Privilege` tracking bar on the Profile Page too light?

**Old Colour:**

[image: Old Colour]

**New Colour:**

[image: New Colour]

Comment: Imo, it is. The new green looks washed out... (Not just on that bar).

Comment: It just doesn't look consistent with other colours like 'next badge' yellow. Other colours feel much warmer compared to this new green.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have much more to offer in way of an answer than what [**TylerH** has already written](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321532/new-colour-scheme-for-next-privilege-bar-too-light/321536#321536):

> [T]he new contrast makes it easier to read. ... This is lighter to indicate that the color is supposed to be in the background (because it's providing background info/context clues rather than primary information), as opposed to foreground greens like the accepted-answer shade of #5fba7d.

This basically sums up the reason why we changed it. [Some people were complaining about the bar's readability previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321420/forgotten-element-at-new-color-theme).

Comment: [Every change breaks something to somebody.](https://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: @Nathan Seems to have broken the code block background and deleted answer background http://i.stack.imgur.com/nFbSR.png :D

Comment: @BhargavRao Link?

Comment: @Hynes Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36794693/4099593, It is within a code block

Comment: @BhargavRao I think that's intended. Within deleted-answers, the code-background is reset. I don't know why, but that looks intentional.

Comment: @Hynes Are you sure? It wasn't like that before. Anyway, it is not a high priority bug, as it is a small problem to 10k+ only.

Comment: @BhargavRao Talked with a co-worker and it seems you are correct. This was changed recently, though I am unsure why. I'll look into it further next week.

Comment: Thanks for that, there is a meta post on this too. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321544/grey-background-doesnt-appear-for-code-in-deleted-answers?lq=1

Comment: Hmmm. While I agree that it is easier to read (great!), it's different than the other greens on the page (the green behind accepted answers) which I think is what makes it look funny.  However, since the votes are in white, changing them to match would make those *harder* to read .... no best way I guess?

Answer (score 7):

Is it too light? No, I don't think so. In fact the new contrast makes it easier to read. The new background color is `#a6d9b7`. This is lighter to indicate that the color is supposed to be in the background (because it's providing background info/context clues rather than primary information), as opposed to foreground greens like the accepted-answer shade of `#5fba7d`.

Comment: I agree with this..I don't think its that bad..it's less disturbing too.