# Grey background doesn't appear for code in deleted answers

Tags: bug, design, code-formatting, deleted-answers

The grey background for code seems to have disappeared for deleted answers. For example, [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36772325/3049655) looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

[This happens on meta as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321545/3049655)

Bug?

I'm using the latest version of Chrome (49.0.2623.105) on Android.

Comment: Confirmed [[meta-tag:bug]] [Refer this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321532/new-colour-scheme-for-next-privilege-bar-too-light/321537?noredirect=1#comment335966_321537)

Comment: Is it really a bug though?  These are deleted questions and answers.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman Why would the background style disappear for code just because the answer is deleted? Syntax highlighting is still there, so styles are still being applied. Therefore the missing background block is a bug rather than a feature.

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  Definitely a bug.  I should have phrased that better.  I was trying to ask if it really matters if it gets fixed or not?  Deleted questions are deleted - the formatting shouldn't really matter that much for them.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy to miss that an answer was deleted if it only contains a code block? It would be mostly gray, with a bit red. So I guess the single red background was on purpose.